# Как считать динамическую строку?

Tags: c++, строки, ввод

Код:

```
string *st;
st = new string; getline(cin, st);
```

Но getline не работает. Как считать st?

Comment: Посмотрите получше тему указатели и вообще работу с памятью в C++, вам это поможет избегать таких ошибок в будущем. В данном случае Вы вместо самой строки передавали указатели на строку, из-за чего `getline` и не работает

Answer (score 3):

`getline` работает, просто надо правильно им воспользоваться.

Непонятно, зачем через динамическую строку... но ладно:

```
string *st;
st = new string; 
getline(cin, *st);
```

Но всё же на мой взгляд так было бы лучше:

```
string st;
getline(cin, st);
```